# Simple AHK script not working

Tags: c++, string, replace, autohotkey

I had read lots of pages on AHK but haven't found any that explains how to make a script that enables me to replace "for" when it's typed by the following:

```
for(int i=0;i<CONDITION;i++)
{

}
```

I would like it to set cursor focus on inside the brackets to start writing the loop-code right away.

Here is what I have came up until now:

```
::for::for(int i=0;i<CONDITION;i++),
{,
    ,
}
```

Should replace "for" with the code at top of the post but gets the following error:

```
Error at line 2.

linetext: ,,
Error: this line does not contain recognised action.

The program will exit.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hotkey (or hotstring) that executes more than one line must list its first line beneath the hotkey (or hotstring).
https://autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#autoexec

Comma, semicolon, and other characters such as {}^!+# have special meaning in AHK and need to be escaped in order to be interpreted differently than it normally would.
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm

```
::for::for(int i=0`;i<CONDITION`;i`{+`}`{+`})`n`{`{`}`n`n`{`}`}{Up}
```

The easiest way to send such a text is this:

```
; #If WinActive("ahk_class Notepad")

::for::
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll  ; save clipboard
clipboard := ""            ; empty clipboard
clipboard =                ; send this text to the clipboard:
(
for(int i=0;i<CONDITION;i++)
{

}
)
ClipWait, 1               ; wait for the clipboard to contain data
Send, ^v
Send, {Up}
clipboard := ClipSaved    ; restore original clipboard
return

; #If
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll use this example to do while and foreach loops :)

Comment: You don't need to use the clipboard to send the text if you use send raw (e.g., see my alternative answer).

Answer (score 2):

Also fairly simple is this approach, which works well in Scite and Notepad++ which handles tabbing automatically:

```
::for::
SendRaw,
(
For(int i=0;i<CONDITION;i++)
{

}
)
Send, {Up}{End}
return
```

Comment: Just commented that didn't do the tabbing for me but I had tested it wrongly :)